# Sort Columns from a Single Row by Number

Tags: php, sorting

I am probably over-thinking this.. but I can't figure this out. I have a database that has five columns. In these columns is a random number 1-6. I am trying to pull this row and then re-sort them either asc or desc- doesn't matter.

```
Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5
---------------------------------
  2  |   1  |   3  |   5  |   4
```

I would like to sort these to know if the rows either show:
1,2,3,4,5 or 5,4,3,2,1.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: generally you sort rows (not columns) you have one row... it will always be sorted (because there's nothing else t sort it by). If you want something different, can you explain a bit more?

Comment: I am trying to determine if they have a 1 in any of the 5 columns, a 2 in any of the 5 columns, a 3 in any of the 5 columns, a 4 in any of the 5 columns and a 5 in any of the 5 columns. I figured re-ordering them would make it easier.. but I'm just trying to determine if all 5 columns have a different number in them.

Comment: so,you're puling out a single row... and ordering the columns based on what's in the column data for that row?

Comment: I think that's what I want to do, yes. If I could do that, I'd accomplish what I'm trying to do. Otherwise.. if I can verify distinct values in those columns, that would work too. So if "col1 != col2 != col3 != col4 != col5" if that makes sense. Because if none of the columns equal each other.. there's 1-5.

Comment: So you probably don't want to be sorting in SQL then, so the PHP answer (below) would be your best bet. PHP has much easier-to-use tools for that kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

Would suggest storing your column values into an array and performing a `sort($column_value_array, SORT_NUMERIC)`

Also have alook at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are only trying to sort an array in `PHP` there is already a function done for that

```
sort ($array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

The method will return a boolean relating to the success state of the sort.

Note that the `sort_flag` is facultative and in your case don't really need to be used.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php for more information.

An other way would be to simply add an `order by` clause to your query when selecting the row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query. This will make sure in each column(any) any of the 1,2,3,4,5 number exists i.e. 5 columns have a different number in them

```
select *,
((LENGTH(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole), '1', ''))) as one,
((LENGTH(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole), '2', ''))) as two,
((LENGTH(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole), '3', ''))) as three,
((LENGTH(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole), '4', ''))) as four,
((LENGTH(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole))) - LENGTH(REPLACE(concat(cola,colb,colc,cold,cole), '5', ''))) as five
from tests
having one = 1 AND two = 1 AND three = 1 AND four = 1 AND five = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
SELECT * from table WHERE

Col1 in (1,2,3,4,5) && 
Col2 in (1,2,3,4,5) &&
Col3 in (1,2,3,4,5) &&
Col4 in (1,2,3,4,5) &&
Col5 in (1,2,3,4,5) &&
Col1 != Col2 &&
Col1 != Col3 &&
Col1 != Col4 &&
Col1 != Col5 &&
Col2 != Col3 &&
Col2 != Col4 &&
Col2 != Col5 &&
Col3 != Col4 &&
Col3 != Col5 &&
Col4 != Col5 &&
```